# Signalr Context Thread Safety

Tags: signalr

We are using SignalR to push messages from server to client. Some of the things we are using server broadcast for:

- Live notifications
- Updating changes of shared data
- Chat like functionality

One of our devs started with the StockTicker example, and we expanded it to push all of our different message types. Here is our general scheme:

```
 private void RunJobs()
    {
        _jobs = GetAllJobs();
        while (true)
        {
            bool workDone = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < _jobs.Count; i++)
            {
                var j = _jobs.ElementAt(i);
                bool workToDo = j.MessageAvailable();
                workDone = workDone || workToDo;

                if (workToDo)
                {
                    var message = j.GetMessage();   
                    _threadPool.QueueWorkItem(ProcessJob, j, message);
                }
            }

            if (!workDone)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(_sleepTime);
            }

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method called by threads to process queued up Work Item (ISignalRJob)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="job">Job to run.</param>
    private void ProcessJob(ISignalRJob job, QueueMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            job.ProcessMessage(message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //handle exception
        }
    }
```

As each job processes, it performs an operation like:

```
protected override void ProcessMessage(QueueMessage message)
    {
        var nqm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotificationQueueMessage>(message.Body);

        var notification = webService.GetNotification(notification.Id);

        foreach(var userConnectionId in GetUserConnectionIds(nqm.UserId)){
             _signalRConnectionContext.Clients.Client(userConnectionId).pushNotification(notification);
        }

    }
```

In a thread, monitor a series of queues for messages. If a message turns up, pop the message off the queue, and start a new thread to process the message (ProcessJob).  The jobs will then do any service calls / db calls necessary to build the client message, then push the message to the client.

The service seems to work, but periodically the client will stop receiving the messages, although I have verified they are being sent from the server. Is it possible that pushing to a client connection in multiple threads is putting it in a bad state?

Should I perhaps be returning the result of the QueueMessage processing to the main SignalR thread, and return them all synchronously?

Comment: When you say that  you have verified the messages have been sent from the server, have you verified the messages have been sent over the wire or simply ensured that `Client(userConnectionId).pushNotification(notification)` has been called?

Comment: I have verified that they have been pushed from the server. I have not verified they have made it out over the wire. Is there are log I can use to see this?  Would it be visible through the Network tab in Chrome development tools?

Comment: It's thread safe so that's not the problem.

Comment: Thanks dfowler, will keep looking.